# Is it possible to integrate an Azure DevOps YAML pipeline into a release pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, cypress, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I've defined a Pipeline to run my Cypress tests and this works fine for running automated tests via a CRON task, or when we want to run it via a manual execution:

```
schedules:
- cron: "0 6 * * *"
  displayName: Daily 6AM test run
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  always: true

strategy:
      parallel: 2

pool:
    vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"

steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
          versionSpec: "12.x"
      displayName: "Install Node.js"

    - task: CacheBeta@1
      inputs:
          key: npm | $(Agent.OS) | package-lock.json
          path: /home/vsts/.npm
          restoreKeys: npm | $(Agent.OS) | package-lock.json
      displayName: Cache NPM packages
    - task: CacheBeta@1
      inputs:
          key: cypress | $(Agent.OS) | package-lock.json
          path: /home/vsts/.cache/Cypress
          restoreKeys: cypress | $(Agent.OS) | package-lock.json
      displayName: Cache Cypress binary

    - script: npm ci
      displayName: "Install NPM dependencies"

    - script: npm run cy:verify
      displayName: "Cypress verify"

    - script: npm run cy:run:staging
      displayName: "run Cypress"

    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@0
      inputs:
          artifactName: "screenshots"
          targetPath: "cypress/screenshots"
      condition: failed()
      displayName: "Publish Screenshots (Cypress)"

    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@0
      inputs:
          artifactName: "videos"
          targetPath: "cypress/videos"
      condition: succeededOrFailed()
      displayName: "Publish Videos (Cypress)"

    - task: PublishTestResults@2
      inputs:
          testResultsFormat: "JUnit"
          testResultsFiles: "**/test-output-*.xml"
          testRunTitle: "Cypress Test Results"
          publishRunAttachments: true
      condition: succeededOrFailed()
      continueOnError: true
```

We have a use case however where we want to run the Cypress test's against a new release pipeline when a new release is generated.

[image]

However, I can't see a way to use the YAML file I have defined in the pipeline as a 'task' for the release pipeline.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: You might look at [Multi-Stage Pipelines](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/azure-devops-pipelines-multi-stage-pipelines-and-yaml-for-continuous-delivery/)

Comment: @Keva161 Not get your latest information, are the following answers helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the [Trigger Build Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks) extension and queue the YAML pipeline from the release:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I can't see a way to use the YAML file I have defined in the pipeline
> as a 'task' for the release pipeline.

For this issue, if you refer to reuse the tasks defined in the yaml pipeline in the release pipeline , I am afraid this is impossible to achieve. You need to convert the tasks defined in the yaml pipeline into corresponding tasks in the classic pipeline one by one.

You can choose to create a task group in the release pipeline to contain these tasks that need to be reused, and then when you need to reuse these tasks, you only need to add this task group. Here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/task-groups?view=azure-devops).

[image]

Or you can integrate the release pipeline into the yaml pipeline to [create a Multi-Stage pipeline](https://mohitgoyal.co/2019/07/30/create-multi-stage-pipelines-with-yaml-in-azure-devops/). Each stage describes the part of the CI/CD process.

Then you can create template yaml file for Cypress test. When [creating a template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#step-reuse), you make a separate YAML file with a set of tasks you want to reuse. To run all of those tasks, all you have to do is reference the template. If you need to run the same set of tasks on different pipelines with a separate YAML file for each pipeline, you can have each YAML file reference the template for those tasks.

About YAML syntax ,please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#stage) .